# QGIS 3.14: Remove intersect points on a line

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-processing

Is there a way to remove the point that intersect with the red line instead of removing it manually?
I tried using geometry checker

[image: Orange point and Red Line]

Comment: Try to `select by location` every point which touches the line (works only, if the line exactly runs through the points), then deleted this points.

Comment: Do the points lie exactely on the line? If not, create a buffer around the line and then continue with this buffer as explained by @Erik

Comment: @Erik 
It only selected few of the points I wonder why. But the line perfectly runs through the point btw.

Comment: Alright. Buffering works! Thanks guys! Learn a lot from you guys!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refers to the comment part!
by @erik and @babel:

- Select by location every point which touches the line (works only, if the line exactly runs through the points), then deleted this points
- And/or create a buffer around the line and then continue with this buffer like above